# SPWorkflowTaskProperties.ExtendedProperties aren’t populating the fields in my task

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, wss

I am attempting to pass information from a task created within a workflow to its corresponding task form.  Prior to the CreateTask activity, I create an SPWorkflowTaskProperties and fill it with the usual info (title, assigned-to, etc).  I also add some elements to the ExtendedProperties property.  However, those custom properties never make it into the Task.

I've tried setting the property key to:

- the Guid of one of my task' content
  type's fields;
- the internal name of
  one of my task' content type's
  fields;
- an unrelated name (in the
  hopes of getting the info into the
  task's properties instead of its
  fields).

Nothing works.  The task, once created, contains only the built-in field values I have set. None of values I explicitly added to the extended properties show up.

The (simplified) sequence of my activities is as follows:

- PrepareTask. This is a custom
  activity that contains the
  SPWorkflowTaskProperties
- CreateTask. The task properties are bound to the one in the PrepareTask activity.
- OnTaskCreated. The task properties are bound to the one in the PrepareTask activity.
- While (task not complete)

  - OnTaskChanged

I am using WSS 3.0 SP1 and an ASPX (NOT InfoPath) task form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't know why my original solution didn't work.  But I have found a workaround.  My sequence of activities is now:

- CreateTask
- OnTaskCreated
- CopyTaskItems.  This is a custom
  activity that puts values into my
  custom task's fields, then updates
  the task.
- While (task not complete)

  - OnTaskChanged

So I have to create the task, then immediately poke values into it and update.

I hope this will help some future reader of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a ItemMetadata.xml document as a secondary datasource that contains the definition of the fields that you want to pass to your task form. Something like:

```
<z:row xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" 
    ows_Instructions="" 
    ows_Body=""
    ows_Comments=""
    ows_ApprovalStatus=""
/>
```

The File name is important btw.

Notice the `ows_` (as it used the webservices all fields in the list will be prefixed with `ows`.)

Then in you infopath form, set the default value of each control you want to display this information in. Hit the fx button and insert a field or group from the secondary datasource.

A good resource: http://weblog.vb-tech.com/nick/archive/2007/02/25/2207.aspx